# Scikit-learn and Keras' MLP very different with same hyperparameters

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tensorflow, keras

I'm using Multilayer Perceptron ANNs at the very beginning of my project (it's a binary classification problem). Because it's simpler, I started with Scikit-learn. I got a magic result, with my model classifying correctly 98% of the test set. Now, I want to move to TensorFlow so I can implement other details, use dropout, and maybe other ANN architectures. The problem is: I tried to replicate the same ANN from sklearn in tensorflow (using Keras), but now my score is 50% (just predicting everything as `1`).

In both code excerpts below, I've used the same pre-treatment for both, having `X_train` and `y_train` as training data and `X_test` and `y_test` as testing data. As it's a binary classification problem, `y_*` is a vector of `1`s and `0`s.

This is my code in sklearn, which prints "Score of the prediction: 0.98 after 373 iterations.":

```python
# ...
clf = MLPClassifier(max_iter=1000, hidden_layer_sizes=(100, 100))
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

print(f"Score of the prediction: {clf.score(X_test, y_test)} after {clf.n_iter_} iterations.")
```

`clf.predict(X_test)`, in this case, is a `numpy.ndarray(dtype=int32)`, having only `1`s and `0`s, just like my original vector `y_test`.

In TensorFlow (with Keras), this is my code:

```python
# ...
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))
model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=min([200, X.shape[0]]), validation_split=0.1)
test_results = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=1)
```

And it prints:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 2s 2s/step - loss: 1.5126 - accuracy: 0.4889 - val_loss: 1.8084 - val_accuracy: 0.6000
```

Here, a `val_accuracy` of `0.6` is not much better than predicting everything as `1` (or everything as `0`). It happens to be the case. `model.predict(X_test)` is a `numpy.ndarray(dtype=float32)` equals to `[0.99999994, 0.99999994, ..., 0.99999994, 1]`.

Looking at the documentation for `sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier`, I found that it's using `batchsize=min([200, X.shape[0]])`, `activation='relu'` and `optmizer='adam'`, exactly like I (tried to) mimick in TF.

The question is: What am I missing?

**Note**: I'm sorry for not providing the datasets, but it's private. However, being the same thing for both libraries, the focus is on the difference.

Comment: @robmeofmyfreedom yes, it should be 1 or 0, a scalar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is I was not defining the number of epochs to train. The poor accuracy came from the first epoch only, while scikit-learn was training for 373 iterations. To solve this, I used the same number os epochs as I was using for `max_iter` in Sklearn (1000), and defined an EarlyStopping Callback. Also, I've read that sigmoid is a better activation function for the output layer in a binary classification.

This is my new code, which works even better than Scikit-learn.

```python
# ...
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))
model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) # now using Sigmoid

# We define a Callback
callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='accuracy', patience=10, mode='max', start_from_epoch=200, baseline=0.9)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Now I set 1000 epochs, with the callback I defined
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=min([200, X.shape[0]]), epochs=1000, callbacks=[callback])
test_results = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
```

The result now is an accuracy of `1.0`.